# How to fix overlap using Expanded and flex in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some trouble fixing a bottom overlap using Expanded with flex in Flutter. What did I do wrong? I want the text widget that says "General" to be below of the Clip Widget that says "Edit profile".

I attach a picture of my problem below the code. I erased some parenthesis to avoid to have too much lines of code and Stack Overflow don't tell me that the post is mostly code.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:money_manager/data/user_info.dart';
import 'package:money_manager/utils/constants.dart';

class HomeProfileTab extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeProfileTab({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: background,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios,
          color: fontSubHeading,
        ),
        actions: const [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: defaultSpacing),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.settings,
              color: fontSubHeading,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(defaultSpacing),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: defaultSpacing,
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(defaultRadius)),
                        child: Image.asset(
                          userdata.picture,
                          width: 100,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: defaultSpacing,
                      ),
                      Text("Jacob Timberline",
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge?.copyWith(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: fontHeading)),
                      Text("jacobtimberline@gmail.com",
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .bodyText2
                              ?.copyWith(color: fontSubHeading)),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: defaultSpacing,
                      ),
                      Chip(
                        backgroundColor: primaryLight,
                        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(defaultRadius * 3)),
                          side: BorderSide(color: primaryLight),
                        ),
                        label: Text(
                          "Edit Profile",
                          style: Theme.of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .bodyText2
                              ?.copyWith(color: Colors.black54),
              ...
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "General",
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1?.copyWith(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, color: fontHeading),
                    ),
                    ...
}
```

This is my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

in your code, you use 2 expanded :

- expanded with flex 1 for the identity data
- expanded with flex 2 for the general data
  it means that the column area will be divide by 3 section, then the identity data get 1 section, then the general data will get 2 section

the bottom overflow is because the height of your identity data is more than the height of the section it get.

i have some solutions you can try :

**solution 1**
you can remove the expanded in the identity data, so the height will be follow your content. so you can just use expanded for general data, and remove the flex(don't need it anymore because it will just get the remaining height available area.

**solution 2**
if you still want to make the identity area 1/3 of the column area, and general data 2/3 area. then you should wrap the center widget of your identity data with singlechildscrollview.
so your column will be look like this :
Expanded > SingleChilScrollView > Center > identity data
Expanded > general data

but i recommend you to use the solution 1, because it will be look more better than the solution 2 (it will make user confuse if they need to scroll to look for the button)